# Assigning a DIV class "checked" status by id, on page load

Tags: addclass, toggleclass

I have a a series of divs (df1, df2, df3, etc...):

`<div class="class_checkbox" id="df1">TEST</div>`

with CSS styling of:

```
.class_checkbox {
  background-color: #FFF;
  opacity: 1;
}

.class_checkbox.checked {
  background-color: #FFF;
  opacity: 1;
}
```

I have an onClick toggleClass that works correctly on all.

But sometimes I need to set certain DIVs checked on page load.

Can't I use:
    `('df1').toggleClass('checked');`

I am not getting the "opacity: 1" to appear of the checked class.  Even if I use

```
$(document).ready(function() {
     $("#df1").addClass("checked");
})
```

What am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 0):

You could do something like this:

```
$(document).ready(function() {
     $("#df1").addClass("checked");
});
```

Comment: I had tried this, even with the # sign.  This doesnt seem to work.